# Pyspark split the spark dataframe of type string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a spark dataframe by reading data from kafka topic using spark(batch processing,not streaming).I wanted to load this dataframe to cassandra using spark.Dataframe is in string format like below.

root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

```
+--------------------+
|value               |
+--------------------+
|"1,Visa,6574"       |
|"3,Visa,6574"       |
|"4,MasterCard,6574" |
|"5,MasterCard,6574" |
|"8,Maestro,8372"    |
+--------------------+
```

I tried to split dataframe record using ',' delimiter and form new dataframe which I could data to cassandra.

created sparkDF like below.

```
df = spark \
.read \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS) \
.option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS) \
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
.load()
df2=df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
df2.printSchema()
```

I tried to split the data using ','.

```
split_col=split(df2['value'],',')
df3=df2.withColumn('Name1',split_col.getItem(0))
df3=df2.withColumn('Name2',split_col.getItem(1))
df3=df2.withColumn('Name3',split_col.getItem(2))
```

Above code is not giving expected result,I am getting put like

root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name3: string (nullable = true)

```
+-------------------+-----+
|value              |Name3|
+-------------------+-----+
|"1,Visa,6574"      |6574"|
|"3,Visa,6574"      |6574"|
|"4,MasterCard,6574"|6574"|
|"5,MasterCard,6574"|6574"|
|"8,Maestro,8372"   |8372"|
+-------------------+-----+
```

I wanted to get the put like below:

```
+-------------------+----------+------+
|Name1              |Name2     |Name3 |
+-------------------+----------+------+
| 1                 |Visa      |6574  |
| 3                 |Visa      |6574  |
| 4                 |MasterCard|6574  |
| 5                 |MasterCard|6574  |
| 8                 |Maestro   |8372  |
+-------------------+----------+------+
```

Pls help !!

Answer (score 3):

Your Solution is perfectly ok. Only problem is the assignment of `df2` and `df3` after doing splits and using for the next step. After doing first split you assigned to `df3` but for subsequent splits you used `df2` only. Hence, only 3rd split statement was evaluated by a spark.

Solution wise either don't assign to a new variable till last split

```
df3 = df2.withColumn('Name1', f.split('value', ',').getItem(0)).\
                 withColumn('Name2', f.split('value', ',').getItem(1)).\
                 withColumn('Name3', f.split('value', ',').getItem(2))

df3.show()
+-----------------+-----+----------+-----+
|            value|Name1|     Name2|Name3|
+-----------------+-----+----------+-----+
|      1,Visa,6574|    1|      Visa| 6574|
|      3,Visa,6574|    3|      Visa| 6574|
|4,MasterCard,6574|    4|MasterCard| 6574|
|5,MasterCard,6574|    5|MasterCard| 6574|
|   8,Maestro,8372|    8|   Maestro| 8372|
+-----------------+-----+----------+-----+
```

or use an assigned variable in next split (Won't encourage to use this way unless it's necessary)

```
df3 = df2.withColumn('Name1', f.split('value', ',').getItem(0))

df3 = df3.withColumn('Name2', f.split('value', ',').getItem(1))

df3 = df3.withColumn('Name3', f.split('value', ',').getItem(2))

df3.show()
+-----------------+-----+----------+-----+
|            value|Name1|     Name2|Name3|
+-----------------+-----+----------+-----+
|      1,Visa,6574|    1|      Visa| 6574|
|      3,Visa,6574|    3|      Visa| 6574|
|4,MasterCard,6574|    4|MasterCard| 6574|
|5,MasterCard,6574|    5|MasterCard| 6574|
|   8,Maestro,8372|    8|   Maestro| 8372|
+-----------------+-----+----------+-----+
```